# Inserir dados se outro INSERT for executado com sucesso

Tags: php

Quero que insira na table.2 os dados SE a primeira inserção, na table.1, for executada com sucesso.

all_processo.php

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title>Cadastro de Processos</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/custom.css">
 <style type="text/css">
 <!--
.loader {
 margin: 0 auto;
  border: 12px solid #000000;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-top: 7px solid black;
  border-right: 7px solid grey;
  border-bottom: 7px solid black;
  border-left: 7px solid grey;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  -webkit-animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
  animation: spin 1s linear infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes spin {
  0% { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); }
  100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); }
}

@keyframes spin {
  0% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
  100% { transform: rotate(360deg); }
}

.center1 {
 text-align: center;
}
<!---->
</style>
</head>
<body>
 <div class='container box-mensagem-crud'>
  <?php 
  require 'conexao.php';

  $conexao = conexao::getInstance();


  $acao  = (isset($_POST['acao'])) ? $_POST['acao'] : '';

 
  $numero = $_POST['numero'];
  $assunto = $_POST['assunto'];
  $requerente = $_POST['requerente'];
  $status = $_POST['status'];
  $informe = $_POST['informe'];
  $data = $_POST['data'];
  $processo_id = (isset($_GET['processo_id']));
  
  if ($acao == 'incluir'):
  
 
 
  $processos = "INSERT INTO processos(numero, assunto, requerente, status)
   VALUES(:numero, :assunto, :requerente, :status)";


   $stm = $conexao->prepare($processos);
   $stm->bindValue(':numero', $numero);   
   $stm->bindValue(':assunto', $assunto);
   $stm->bindValue(':requerente', $requerente);
   $stm->bindValue(':status', $status);
   $retorno = $stm->execute();
   
   if ($retorno == 1){
    
    $lastid = $conexao->lastInsertId();
   
   $informes = "INSERT INTO informes(informe, data, processo_id)
   VALUES (:informe, :data, :processo_id = $lastid)";
   
   $tsm = $conexao->prepare($informes);
   $tsm->bindValue(':informe', $informe);
   $tsm->bindValue(':data', $data);
   $tsm->bindValue(':processo_id', $processo_id);
   $lol = $tsm->execute();
   
   }else{
    if ($retorno == 0){
    
    echo "<div class='' role='alert'>Erro nos informes!</div>";
    echo "<div class=''</div>";

   echo "<meta http-equiv=refresh content='3;URL=registrarprocesso.php'>";
   }
   }
   
   if ($lol):
   
    echo "teste";
    echo "<div class='center1' role='alert'>Processo inserido com sucesso, aguarde você está sendo redirecionado...</div> ";
    echo "<div class='loader'</div>";
      else:
       echo "<div class='center1' role='alert'>Erro ao inserir processo, aguarde!</div>";
    echo "<div class='loader'</div>";
   endif;

   echo "<meta http-equiv=refresh content='4;URL=listarprocessos.php'>";
   
   
  endif;

?>
```

table.1:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

table.2:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: O que está a acontecer no momento? Só insere a primeira?  Veja o conteúdo de POST `var_dump($_POST);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2º `INSERT` apenas se o 1º acontecer:

```
<?php
    require 'conexao.php';
    $conexao = conexao::getInstance();
    $acao  = (isset($_POST['acao'])) ? $_POST['acao'] : '';
    $numero = $_POST['numero'];
    $assunto = $_POST['assunto'];
    $requerente = $_POST['requerente'];
    $status = $_POST['status'];
    $informe = $_POST['informe'];
    $data = $_POST['data'];
    $processo_id = (isset($_GET['processo_id']));
    if ($acao == 'incluir'){
        $processos = "INSERT INTO processos(numero, assunto, requerente, status)VALUES(:numero, :assunto, :requerente, :status)";
        $stm = $conexao->prepare($processos);
        $stm->bindValue(':numero', $numero);
        $stm->bindValue(':assunto', $assunto);
        $stm->bindValue(':requerente', $requerente);
        $stm->bindValue(':status', $status);
        if($stm->execute()){
            $lastid = $conexao->lastInsertId();
            //************** aqui entram os valores que faltam *******************
            $informes = "INSERT INTO informes(de_setor, para_setor, informe, data, informante, processo_id)VALUES (:de_setor, :para_setor, :informe, :data, :informante, :processo_id)";
            $tsm = $conexao->prepare($informes);
            $tsm->bindValue(':de_setor', $de_setor);
            $tsm->bindValue(':para_setor', $para_setor);
            $tsm->bindValue(':informe', $informe);
            $tsm->bindValue(':data', $data);
            $tsm->bindValue(':informante', $informante);
            $tsm->bindValue(':processo_id', $lastid);
            if($tsm->execute()){
                echo "teste";
                echo "<div class='center1' role='alert'>Processo inserido com sucesso, aguarde você está sendo redirecionado...</div> ";
                echo "<div class='loader'</div>";
            }else{
                echo "<div class='center1' role='alert'>Erro ao inserir processo, aguarde!</div>";
                echo "<div class='loader'</div>";
            }
        }else{
            echo "<div class='' role='alert'>Erro nos informes!</div>";
            echo "<div class=''</div>";
            echo "<meta http-equiv=refresh content='3;URL=registrarprocesso.php'>";
        }
        echo "<meta http-equiv=refresh content='4;URL=listarprocessos.php'>";
    }
?>
```

Havia também um erro no segundo `INSERT` e no `bind_param()`.

Caso os valores de `de_setor, para_setor e informante` já existam, provenientes de outra consulta, passe os valores para cá, ou faça uma query para trazer os valores.

Comment: Continua inserindo apenas a primeira inserção =/

To preso nisso há umas semanas, não sei como proceder

Comment: da um no `var_dump($tsm->execute())`

Comment: bool(false)

o que significa?

Comment: naõ inseriu, problema na query então

Comment: Nome da tabela ta certo?

Comment: Ja achei o erro, os campos da tabela estão marcando como `Não pode Ser NulL`, e vc ta tentando inserir na tabela faltando dados

Comment: ué?

eu to completando todo formulário... que estranho

Comment: Tabela 2 tem 6 campos "obrigatorios", por estarem `Nulo = Não`, e vc esta tentando inserir apenas 3

Comment: Faltam valores para  "de_setor, para_setor e informante"

Comment: são tipo int

de_setor, para_setor e informante são puxados direto do banco de dados.

Comment: mas vc tem q passar ai no `INSERT` porque se não ele não aceita o cadastro, só o `AUTO_INCREMENT` que preenche sozinho ai na tabela

Comment: e coloco tipo GET?

Comment: vc disse que são puxados do banco de dados certo? Então basta adicionar esses valores ai, vou editar a resposta pra vc ver onde ficarão

Comment: eu fiz como o editado, preenchi as variaveis ( $de_setor = (isset($_GET['de_setor']));
 $para_setor = (isset($_GET['para_setor']));
    $informe = $_POST['informe'];
    $data = $_POST['data'];
 $informante = (isset($_GET['informante']));)

porém nada disso mudou o resultado, continua não inserindo a segunda tabela

Comment: mas os valores estão sendo passados por GET? e vc usando POST no código? É um ou outro

Comment: sou muito lerdo

mesmo não podendo, agradeço pelo teu tempo, obrigado mesmo!

Comment: Eu quem agradeço por poder ajudar, e é assim mesmo, as vezes é um ponto que foi errado que a gnt quebra a cabeça pra achar